# Anaconda training tends to interruption

Tags: anaconda, generative-adversarial-network, pre-trained-model

I encountered an issue while training network weights using Anaconda prompt: If the computations are complex and each epoch takes a long time, the program tends to automatically pause until I press the "Enter" key on the keyboard to resume training, and it happens frequently.

What causes this issue and how to avoid it?